# SQLite open database returns error code 14 but only when the db file was created via cp command

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I'm trying to open an external SQLite database that I copy over from another location to the app's file direcory like so:

```
Runtime.getRuntime.exec("su -c cp <path to .db> <dest path>");
```

However, trying to open it with openDatabase() returns error code 14. I verified that the file actually was copied and that proper permissions were set.

But if I copy the file over using a file manager, then openDatabase() is successful. Both files had the same filesize and permissions.

What do I do here?

EDIT:
The supposedly corrupt file I get from cp starts working if I make a copy of it using a  file manager.

Comment: so what is the output of `adb shell ls -l path` in both cases?

Comment: @pskink
 -rw-r--r-- root     root      1613824 2017-11-08 20:05 browser.db                                                                                                                                                       -rw-r--r-- root     root      1613824 2017-11-08 19:57 browser2.db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to SELinux and was solved by changing the context labels using `chcon`.